# Trying to find the supremum of a given set.

Tags: real-analysis

B = 1 + $1\over 2^n$, where n is any positive even number.
I need to find the supremum of a given set, what I know is that we do reverse engineering over here, we know that 2 is the supremum of the set, so I said let there be an $\epsilon$ > 0 such that

1 + $1\over 2^n$ > 2 - $\epsilon$

and then I proceeded solving it to get

n < $\log_{2}({1 \over 1-\epsilon})$

but that shouldn't come because how else would I use Archimedian property and do the reverse proof?

Comment: What's an “even number” in this context? Do you mean an element of the set $\{2,4,6,\ldots\}$? Or of the set $\{0,2,4,\ldots\}$? Or some other set?

Comment: They haven't said anything, they just said even, so that should include 0 as well

Comment: If $n$ can be negative then ${1 \over 2^n}$ is unbounded. Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: n cannot be negative, there are no negative even numbers

Comment: Please edit and correct your question.

Comment: I wrote that n are even numbers

Comment: Are you claiming that $-2$ is not an even number?

Comment: @KutubkhanBhatiya There absolutely *are* negative even numbers: $-2, -4, -6, \ldots$. An even number is just a number of the form $2k$, where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ (negative, positive, or zero). Perhaps you define even numbers differently, but you need to specify this in your question, because it would not be a standard definition. I would say "non-negative even integer" to specify $\{0, 2, 4, \ldots\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that negative numbers can be even.

Comment: Why don't you just use the first and the second derivative tests?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I cannot use derivatives now as this is our first course in university, so we are not supposed to use them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that, for you, the set of even numbers is $\{0,2,4,\dots\}$.

Let $S=\left\{1+\frac1{2^n}:n\in\{0,2,4,\dots\}\right\}$. Then $2\in S$, since $2=1+\frac1{2^0}$. And every element of $S$ is either $2$ or smaller than $2$. So, $2$ is an upper bound of $S$ and, since it is the lowest upper bound, $2=\sup S$.

Comment: I actually knew this method, but I wanted to do it with the method which I was doing, or can you point out some mistake in my solution?

Comment: Using your approach, it's also simple: you just take $n=0$. That will do, since $1+\frac1{2^0}=2>2-\varepsilon$.

Comment: my main problem is the thing which i did in the question is right, right?, But if it is right it should come that n>(...) but it is coming the opposite, I cant figure out why's that happening.

Comment: Why? If $n$ is very large, then $1+\frac1{2^n}$ is basically $1$. Why would it be greater than $2-\varepsilon$? The *larger* $n$ is, the *smaller* $1+\frac1{2^n}$ becomes. But you want it to be bigger than $2-\varepsilon$. That can only occur for a small number of $n$'s.

Comment: Ohh yeah got it, I dont know what I was thinking